# Is there a way to quick switch between virtual desktops in win10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, shortcuts

On win10, I can switch between different virtual desktops using the following shortcuts:

1. Ctrl + Super + Left: go to the left desktop
2. Ctrl + Super + Right: go to the right desktop

However, I don't think it's fast enough for me. For example, if I want to go to desktop 8 from desktop 2, I have to press `Ctrl + Super + Right` for 6 times, that's not convenient.

I would like the following command:

1. Super + 1: go to desktop 1
2. Super + 2: go to desktop 2
   ...
3. Super + 9: go to desktop 9

Or something like that, so I can quickly switch to a specific desktop using only one shortcut. Is that possible?

Comment: Use this app to set which ever hotkeys you'd like...https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 26):

I found this excellent AutoHotKey script to help me achieve that.

https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher

But by default it uses CapsLock as the modifier key, which is not what I want. I tweaked the script a little bit to make it work by using the `win` key.

https://github.com/searene/windows-desktop-switcher

Now I can switch between desktops by `win + 1`, `win + 2`, etc.

Comment: It's worth noting that win + number is already assigned to open applications in the taskbar in the location corresponding to that number. This script will override this behavior

Comment: It should also be noted that the AHK script doesn't work perfectly, and sometimes doesn't quite get to the desktop you tell it.

Comment: Seems like the script sometimes glitches out, if I switch to say desktop 4, then switch back to 1, everything breaks for some reason. (the task view starts blinking in and out until I terminate the script) The original script however which has seen further development works great and can easily be modified to use the win keys to switch desktop. Personally I prefer ctrl+f1 through f4 for this, and I was able to set this in the user_config file of the original script without issue. Here's a paste with the file edited for the win+num behavior: https://pastebin.com/dbvUn8hG

Comment: the `github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher` works like a charm, I thought I wouldn't like the capslock hotkey but it works really well!

Comment: For me, the modified script breaks the desktop experience
https://youtu.be/9f849Ah9Et4

Comment: Windows 11 now shows the desktop, so the change to the desktops is slowed quite a bit. Are there ways to stop the desktop eye candy from showing?

Answer (score 11):

Currently there exists only these [virtual desktop](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/04/16/virtual-desktops-in-windows-10-the-power-of-windowsmultiplied/) related keyboard shortcuts:

> - WIN + CTRL + LEFT/RIGHT: Switch to previous or next desktop
> - WIN + CTRL + D: Create a new desktop
> - WIN + CTRL + F4: Close the current desktop
> - WIN + TAB: Launch task view

However, Microsoft is developing Windows 10 all the time and likes to have feedback. All kind of new features are tested and evaluated by users in [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com), giving you the upcoming features earlier and power to vote.

Comment: Thank you, that's a little disappointing, I do hope they have a way to switch to a specific desktop with one shortcut.

Comment: I would find WIN + CTRL + number the most intuitive. However, with the unlimited amount of virtual desktops they'd run out quickly.

Comment: I can switch to different program pinned in the taskbar via `WIN + 1`, `WIN + 2`, etc. Although I can only switch between 10 pinned programs, the shortcut is still useful. I think `WIN + CTRL + number` is intuitive enough and would be very helpful if it's available.

Comment: If only a user can define own shortcut bindings, it would probably be another OS.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like this program is worth mentioning as well:

https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer

It has support for direct desktop switching through DLL calls without having to go through the ones in between and the animation can be disabled as well in favor of speed.
Another big plus is that the hotkeys can be configured with an easy to understand `settings.ini`, so no AutoHotKey knowledge is required for that.

(AutoHotKey isn't even required for running the app, since it is compiled into an exe.)

Answer (score 1):

I use VirtuaWin with the VirtuaPlus and WinList modules. Free from 'sourceforge.net' You can create your own shortcuts for moving an active window to a numbered desktop and follow or not. Desktops can have custom names as well as backgrounds. I use four with a dual monitor system for my current workflow.

-Rick

Comment: Sorry about not including the link...  https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtuawin/?source=directory