# Better virtual desktop switching in Win10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

To switch virtual desktops in Windows 10, one has to use the Task View, or use the keyboard shortcuts.

Is there a way to have virtual desktops buttons (or at least arrows) on the task bar, like in Linux's KDE and GNOME environments, so one can switch virtual desktops with a single click?

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1214512/is-there-a-way-to-quick-switch-between-virtual-desktops-in-win10)

Comment: Not with the buildin tools. But there are other Virtual Desktop solutions that can do this, but that would turn this question in a Software Recommendation, and that is considered Off-Topic here on SuperUser. But if you google for Virtual Desktop Windows, you'll find lots of tools that can do this.

Comment: I'd love something like the gnome shell extension "Workspaces to Dock" at the minimum, which I use in auto-hide mode(in fact, although a little flakey, I love the gnome shell extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it has been two years since the original question, I have not seen a reply which describes a way to switch virtual desktops using taskbar buttons. This thread still shows up in my searches on the topic, so for future reference here is an approach using a toolbar of shortcuts:

[image: Desktop Switch Toolbar with Tooltip]

In summary:

1. Install either [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) or [DesktopSwitcher](https://github.com/isobit/win10-desktop-switcher), whichever you prefer.  Either one switches to a desktop specified on its command line.
2. Create a folder to contain the toolbar's shortcuts.
3. Create a shortcut to **VDesk.exe** or **DesktopSwitcher.exe**.  Edit the "Target" command line to specify a desktop number.  For VDesk, specify a dummy executable to run; **rundll32.exe** is a good choice.
4. Make a copy of the shortcut for each virtual desktop.  Change each copy's desktop number, name, and icon, as appropriate for the desktop's purpose.
5. Add the folder as a new toolbar.  If desired, drag the toolbar to the left side of the taskbar, next to the **Task View** button.
6. For one-click desktop selectors, turn OFF the toolbar's **Show Title** and **Show Text** options, then expand the toolbar until all its shortcut icons are visible.  Alternatively, expand it part way to show some icons and an overflow menu.
7. Changes to the shortcuts are automatically reflected in the toolbar.  You can drag the toolbar icons to any order desired, or click right on any entry in the toolbar's '»' menu and select **Sort by Name**.

For details, screen captures, rationale, and limitations, see [Create a One-Click Toolbar to Switch Virtual Desktops](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/159382-create-one-click-toolbar-switch-virtual-desktops-windows-10-a.html#post1950064).

Comment: Hi George, welcome to StackExchange! Thanks for your contribution. Please note that it is a good practice to describe the solution in this site, even if you just need to copy-paste the content. Links should only be here for reference. If for any reason the link stops working, the solution will still be available here. ;-) Cheers.

Comment: I added a summary.  The post I referred to is a tutorial comprising some 200 lines of text, eight in-line images, and many links to other tutorials in the same forum.  Too much to maintain in two places with different source formats. 
 


I tried to embed a screen capture, but an error message said I don't have enough reputation to do that.  So I linked to it instead.

Comment: Looks good, great job! ^_^

Comment: I agree. I don't know why someone downvoted your answer, it is well explained and it addresses OP's main concern. I understand that being downvoted in your first answer can feel very discouraging. :( But I hope you will ignore that and keep contributing. :) Votes aren't always logical, people vote randomly, trends are only observable when lots of people vote. And lots of people give feedback instead of downvoting, so if any particular answer has logical reasons to be downvoted chances are you'll get an explanation. Give it time, keep answering questions and you'll get upvotes over time. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Please see VirtualDesktopEnhancer project on GitHub, maybe it will be useful to you.

https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.